# Does embedding a rectangle in a plane have additional properties compared to embedding a segment?

Tags: general-topology, plane-curves

Let $f: [0, 1] \times [-ε, + ε] \to \mathbb{R}^2$ a topological embedding. Does the restriction of $f$ to $[0, 1] \times \{0\}$ have any additional properties in comparison with the topological embeddings of the segment $f: [0, 1] \to \mathbb{R}^2$?

Comment: One can embed $[0,1]$ as a spiral that circles the origin infinitely many times (yet one of its ends is the origin). I feel one cannot do this with $[0, 1] \times [-ε, + ε]$ but one needs to be more precise. (Alternatively one could make $\frac12$ go to the origin = "center of spiral", "like in a galaxy", if that is of any help to make the corresponding $[0, 1] \times [-ε, + ε]$ embedding impossible. But I need to think of proofs, and of what I try to show ... and what the question asks.)

Comment: @Mirko I can feel it too! It seems that at the end of the spiral we will have to glue $[-ε, +ε]$ into one point. But I don’t know how to prove it, and I’m not even sure if it’s true, so I am asking a question here.

Comment: re the spiral, the endpoint *might* be ok, if one identifies $[0,1]$ with the long diagonal of a rhombus, which in turn is same as $[0, 1]\times[-ε,ε]$. But I tend to believe that if an interior point of $[0,1]$ goes to the center of the spiral then indeed one would have to glue $[-ε,ε]$ to a point. I also wonder if $[0, 1] \times \{0\}$ might have to be rectifiable. Finally, an Osgood curve might be relevant, this is an arc of positive area: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Osgood_curve (I wonder if $[0, 1]\times[-ε,ε]$ would have to have $0$ area).

Comment: Bicollared embedding is the keyword

Comment: @AlessandroCodenotti Thank you!